WinUI3 application does not restart with administrator privileges on Windows 11
I’m trying to implement a program restart asking the user for admin rights for the WinUI3 application. The application uses Windows Update API and I need this functionality to allow the user to install updates available on their OS. I have encountered a problem that restarting with administrator privileges only works on Windows 10 devices, but on Windows 11 the application does not restart. Could you please advise me what could be the problem?
As a result, I would like to get the application restarted with administrator privileges on Windows 11. I used this code to restart the program.
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = Process.GetCurrentProcess(). MainModule.FileName,
    UseShellExecute = true,
    Verb = "runas",
    Arguments = string. Join(" ", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(). Skip(1))
};

try
{
    var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

if (process != null)
    {
        Process.GetCurrentProcess(). Kill();
    }

return true;
}
catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
{
    return false;
}


If you want to run the app as administrators, you could set RequestedExecutionLevel to requireAdministrator. If you want to restart a WinUI app, you could try to use Restart API.

@Jeaninez-MSFT, Thank you for your response! The solution you suggested is not quite suitable for my case, because I need to provide for the option when a user starts the application without administrator rights - to give him an opportunity to press one button to restart the application with the choice of administrator privileges. The code I mentioned solves this problem, but it works properly only for Windows 10.
